# How to take two numbers after decimal point , Number is -7.922816251426434e+28 in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, rounding, points, decimalformat

I need to take just two numbers after decimal point, I'm getting weird numbers in json response which I have to handle , numbers like -7.922816251426434e+28

```
HoldedQuantity.toStringAsFixed(2);
```

I just tried this method but not working, how can I handle such numbers in flutter dart please help out

Comment: If it's `e+28` then it's too large for floating-point precision to have any decimal places.

Comment: If you need to handle arbitrarily large numbers and want decimal precision, try [`package:decimal`](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround

```
void main() {
  var number = -7.922816251426434e+28;
  print(appToStringAsFixed(number, 2)); // -7.92
}

String appToStringAsFixed(double number, int afterDecimal) {
  return '${number.toString().split('.')[0]}.${number.toString().split('.')[1].substring(0,afterDecimal)}';
}
```

or as an extension

```
void main() {
  var number = -7.922816251426434e+28;
  print(number.expToStringAsFixed(2)); // -7.92
}

extension DecimalUtil on double {
  String expToStringAsFixed(int afterDecimal) => '${this.toString().split('.')[0]}.${this.toString().split('.')[1].substring(0,afterDecimal)}';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

double num1 = double.parse((12.3412).toStringAsFixed(2));
// 12.34

double num2 = double.parse((12.5668).toStringAsFixed(2));
// 12.57

double num3 = double.parse((-12.3412).toStringAsFixed(2));
// -12.34

double num4 = double.parse((-12.3456).toStringAsFixed(2));

```
1.toStringAsFixed(3);  // 1.000
(4321.12345678).toStringAsFixed(3);  // 4321.123
(4321.12345678).toStringAsFixed(5);  // 4321.12346
123456789012345678901.toStringAsFixed(3);  // 123456789012345683968.000
1000000000000000000000.toStringAsFixed(3); // 1e+21
5.25.toStringAsFixed(0); // 5
```

Comment: This is what I have done before please see my question , it's not working